# Convert PNG to JPG using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, png, jpeg

I've looked on many sites including SO and cannot find a reliable method for converting PNG to JPG using just JavaScript.

I tried the following using canvas:

```
var imageDataJpeg = document.getElementById('pic5-canvas').toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

But the resulting image is broken and has no data.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Maybe the original image is [tainted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), have you took a look at the Dev console?

Comment: @BadPiggie I saw that post and it did not work for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Teemu nothing seems to show in the console in Firefox. Is there some way to determine if the image is tainted?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature (marked with `<>`) in the question editor.

Comment: Just read the MDN article I've linked to above.